# MapMaker interoperability

Tags: interoperability, map-maker

A consultant has stated that they will use [MapMaker GIS Software](http://www.mapmaker.com) for a piece of work involving GIS analysis and that it is compatible with ArcGIS.

The work will involve analysing many datasets, predominantly in SHP format to produce a land management strategy - the outputs of which will need to feedback into our corporate system (PostGIS server / ArcMap desktop).

From the website it seems that it will import SHP files, but no mention of export. It looks like a cartographic tool rather than capable of GIS analysis.

Can you comment on its suitability for my task and on its interoperability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapMaker Pro will export

Excel spreadsheet
As with DBF files you can import an Excel spreadsheet if it has columns for the coordinates.
Note to import Access or Excel data you need Microsoft ADO, ADOX, and Jet Engine
4.0 installed.

Export files
Remember that in Map Maker information on the appearance of styles is not stored in
the vector file but is stored separately in style files. Some vector formats such as MIF
and DXF files, contain stylistic information (e.g. line styles). This information is ignored
both in import and export.

DXF
When a DRA file is exported to a DXF file all the objects a placed in the default DXF layer called “0”.

ArcView shape files
To export a DRA file as a SHP file

DBase file with X and Y (DBF)
Conventional DBF database files can be used to store point objects. To be recognised as
a legitimate vector file by Map Maker the DBF file must contain two columns containing the X and Y ordinates. A window similar to that for CSV files (above) is displayed where youshould choose the correct columns.

Microsoft Access MDB database
As with DBF files you can import an MDB table if it has columns

NIMA VMAP0 (Digital Chart of the World)
For importing VMAP0 data see the chapter on World Map Projections.

csv
A file of comma separated text

http://www.mapmaker.com/downloads/manual.pdf

The software is a little dated and there is no option for Geodatabase or KML export.