# Seeking advice on Map Maker Pro versus QGIS?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, map-maker

I am an ecologist in the process of trying to decide whether to purchase Map Maker Pro or utilize the free open-source QGIS platform. Most of our needs are associated with basic map making.

I am a novice in the GIS world.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Your question (as currently written) is likely to be flagged as "primarily opinion based", since there really isn't enough information to make an objective judgement. Personally, I'd suggest trying QGIS, and if it meets your needs, why not keep using it?

Comment: Adding to @BradHards, if you happen to need custom functionality on QGIS (unlikely because of the wide variety of existing tools), pay it with the money you'd spend on Map Maker Pro. This way you help both yourself and the community.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond cost, ask yourself:

- Do you need to use any Map Maker Pro-specific data formats, or are you only using Shapefiles?
- Are there any Map Maker Pro-specific capabilities / functionalities you require?
- Do you plan on expanding the size and scale of your data in the future, which might potentially involve moving into a database such as SpatialLite or even PostGIS? QGIS would handle this upgrade better (see this question re. [map maker pro interoperability](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/is-mapmaker-interoperable))

Those are some things that I would think about.